# My timestamps are not enabling, it shows be error

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cross-platform

I just want to use timeago package and for that I am trying to enable timestamps by writing this following code, but it shows error(red Line underneath) while writing it.Also I am using
timeago: ^2.0.26 and cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7.

```
void main() {
  Firestore.instance.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true).then((_) {
    print("Timestamps enabled in snapshots\n");
  }, onError: (_) {
    print("Error enabling timestamps in snapshots\n");
  });
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Firestore.instance.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true).then((_)
```

This way of enabling timestamp is depreciated now and the parameter is not needed as the timestamp is enabled by default.

But you have to explicitly tell the program that you're waiting for some data or running an async function inside the main function. The code for that is given below:

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

**So the Entire code would look like this**

```
void main() {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //The reason behind this is I am waiting for some data or running an async function inside main().
  
  Firestore.instance.settings().then((_) {
    print("Timestamps enabled in snapshots\n");
  }, onError: (_) {
    print("there was an error enabling timestams in snapshots");
  });
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```